# Hover data and click data from dash_table on dash

Tags: python, tooltip, plotly-dash

I have created dash_table on dashboard. I want hoverdata from table when I am hovering mouse and clickdata when I am clicking on any cell from table.
I have used following code to get the active cell index. But I don't know how to use it for fetching datatable cell value.

```
@app.callback(Output('click-data', 'children'),
    [Input('datatable', 'active_cell')])
def display_click_data(active_cell):
    return json.dumps(active_cell, indent=2)
```

Please guide how to use tooltip parameter in dash table.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding your first question (A) how to get the active cell's value, you can pass the table data as `State` to your callback and then simply pick the selected row and column.

To address your second question (B) and use tooltips for the selected cells (hover is not implemented yet), the example from the official [docs](https://dash.plotly.com/datatable/tooltips) works just fine.

Please find a minimal example below (dash-1.19.0, dash_table-4.11.2):

```
# import modules    
import json    
import pandas as pd    
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import dash_table

# prepare dash_table    
size = 5
df = pd.DataFrame([], index=range(size))
df['num'] = range(size)
df['char'] = list('abcdefghijk')[:size]    
tab = dash_table.DataTable(
    id='table',
    columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df.columns],
    data=df.to_dict('records'),
    tooltip_data=[
        {
            # (B) multiply cell value by 10 for demonstration purpose
            column: {'value': str(value*10), 'type': 'markdown'}
            for column, value in row.items()
        } for row in df.to_dict('records')
    ],
    tooltip_delay=0,
    tooltip_duration=None
)

# set layout    
app = dash.Dash('SimpleExample')     
app.layout = html.Div([
    tab,
    html.Div(id='click-data', style={'whiteSpace': 'pre-wrap'}),

])

# define callback        
@app.callback(
    Output('click-data', 'children'),
    [Input('table', 'active_cell')],
     # (A) pass table as data input to get current value from active cell "coordinates"
    [State('table', 'data')]
)
def display_click_data(active_cell, table_data):
    if active_cell:
        cell = json.dumps(active_cell, indent=2)    
        row = active_cell['row']
        col = active_cell['column_id']
        value = table_data[row][col]
        out = '%s\n%s' % (cell, value)
    else:
        out = 'no cell selected'
    return out
 
# run app    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: This is great! I noticed that when I sort the table that the active cell changes relative to the raw table. The result is that the click would get the wrong value. I disabled sorting for now but was wondering if I'm missing something obvious

Comment: Are hover events for dash tables still unsupported?